# Resizing Background Colour without using an image

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to make a flag by only using font-awesome and a background colour. However, I can only get it to work by using a url to a background image, which allows me to change its size. position and repeat. If I use a background colour, I am not able to do so.

To reiterate, I only want my background colour to appear in a certain location, and I do not want to load resources from a url and instead work with background colour.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
        
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave-alt" id="flag"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
#flag{
    
    /*Icon colour is changed to default green*/
    color : green;
    
    /*The colour red is taken from folder*/
    background : url("red.jpg");
    
    
    background-size: 30% 40%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    border-radius : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```css
#flag {
  /*Icon colour is changed to default green*/
  color: green;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-size: 30% 40%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

<i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave-alt fa-5x" id="flag"></i>
```

Using the same color inside the gradient will result on **one color gradient** and gradient behave like image so you can easily adjust their size and position like you do with images:

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-position:20% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also use a [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) in case you want to have circular shape (which is also suitable in your actual example):

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:radial-gradient(circle at center, red 60%,transparent 61%);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-position:20% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And here is with your code:

```css
#flag {
  /*Icon colour is changed to default green*/
  color: green;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 60%,transparent 61%);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

<i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave-alt fa-5x" id="flag"></i>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply replace your css code 
from

```
/*Icon colour is changed to default green*/
color : green;
/*The colour red is taken from folder*/
background : url("red.jpg");
background-size: 30% 40%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
border-radius : 100%;
```

to

```
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: red;
display:block;
```

Note : Display style  block is mandatory, because  you are using "i TAG (an inline element)" .